# direct Global viable access using an "Application" class?

Tags: android

i want to setup a global variable class holder extending "Application" like this one here:

http://trace.adityalesmana.com/2010/08/declare-global-variable-in-android-via-android-app-application/

my question is it possible to access the viable directly instead of calling a method?

(going by the link's example) can "islogin" be declared as:

```
public boolean isLogin = true;
```

then accessed like this?:

```
if (!combankDroid.isLogin) {
```

Comment: I wouldn't _recommend_ it, but sure, you _could_ do that. What's the problem?

Comment: well my app is a media player and the problem a have is the UI tend to loose control of the MediaPlayer instance when the phone is rotated from portrait to landscape (stop button, pause button...etc no longer works). i think globizing the MediaPlayer might fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want: global variables on Application objects work just fine.

The actual solution to your issue is to make the MediaPlayer instance a variable of a Service and then connect to that to fetch/control the MediaPlayer.